# Why does Xrandr's state of output is different in QEMU/KVM guest?

Tags: x11, kvm, qemu

I have just started playing with QEMU.  One thing I have noticed is that the available resolutions listed by xrandr is different from what is available on my host.

I would like to change the resolution on my guest to `2560x1440` which is available on my host but not my guest.

I am using Virtio (video Virtio) & Spice server for Display.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue:

This is from my host:

```
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

This is in my guest:

```
   Virtual-1 connected primary 2048x1152+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 325mm x 203mm
   1280x800      74.99 +
   5120x2160     50.00
   4096x2160     50.00
   3840x2160     60.00    50.00    59.94
   1920x1440     60.00
   2560x1080     50.00
   1856x1392     60.00
   1792x1344     60.00
   2048x1152     60.00*
   1920x1200     59.88
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1400x1050     59.98
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1360x768      60.02
   1280x768      59.87
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   640x480       60.00    59.94
```

Comment: Did you install the spice-vdagent package? What virtual GPU did you select?

Comment: @ajgringo619 - yes and it is running.  Sorry I don't see an option for GPU but as stated in the OP I am using Diplay-Spice (spice-server) & VideoVirtio (Virtio)...does that answer your question?  Or did I miss a setting?

Comment: No, you're good. Since the GPU is virtual, and therefore generic, you'll probably get the same available resolutions on every VM. My Arch VM, running on a host with 1920x1080, shows the exact same resolutions as yours.

Comment: Oh, ok...so that is the resolution provided by the virtual gpu - got it.  Pls add it as an answer so I can mark it - thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% certain that the vGPUs all have the same resolutions available with VirtIO, so I'm going to refrain from posting that as an answer. Since it's what I use, it just made sense. I would suggest looking at QXL vGPU to see if that gives you what you want.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I see your point.  Let me follow that lead and post back any findings...